# How would I solve these system of congruence equations using the Chinese Remainder Theorem since they are not coprime?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The system of equations is:

$X\equiv 5 \bmod 15$

$X\equiv 2 \bmod 12$

I tried splitting up the second equation into modulo $3$ and modulo $ 4 $ as shown below to get $3$ equations in total, but then I think all pairwise mods are still not relatively prime.

$X \equiv 2 \bmod 3$ and $X\equiv2 \bmod 4$ and from before $X\equiv 5 \bmod 15$.

Answer (score 1):

From the first equation, you have $$X\equiv2\pmod 3\\X\equiv0\pmod5$$ and the second equation has $$X\equiv2\pmod 3\\X\equiv2\pmod 4$$

Since the systems of congruences agree on their common modulus, they are compatible, and you just need to solve the three reduced equations with (now pairwise relatively prime) moduli.

Answer (score 0):

$x\equiv5\mod15\implies x\equiv2\mod3$ and $x\equiv0\mod 5$.

$x\equiv2\mod12\implies x\equiv2 \mod 3$ and $x\equiv2\mod 4$.

So we have $x\equiv2 \mod3, x\equiv0 \mod 5$, and $x\equiv2 \mod 4$.

Can you now get a solution mod $60$?

Comment: Oh okay can you just explain how did you split the first equation like that?

Comment: If $15|x-5$ then $3|x-5$ and $5|x-5$ so $3|x-2$ and $5|x$